# Evince shows font in too big style when opening pdf from Internet

Tags: evince

When choose some PDF document to be opened by Evince from a WWW-site, it shows the document with font size 300%. How can I change it to show the document by font size 100 %? The same issue occurs both in Firefox and in Chrome. I'm using Ubuntu 12.10, Evince 3.6.0, Firefox 16.0.1 and Chrome 22.0.1229.94.

Comment: Is this the same for all PDF readers? Can you link to an example PDF?

Comment: I haven't learned how can I change which reader opens PDF's. For example http://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.3720 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem *might* be that you're missing a font.

In some PDFs, not all fonts are embedded, which means that you have to have these fonts installed on your system. If you don't have them installed, the PDF readers use a substitution font, which looks right most of the time, but not always. Looking at your provided sample, you can see in the `emb` column which fonts are embedded:

```
user@host ~ $ pdffonts 1210.3720.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
ZVTVKO+CMR9                          Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no      65  0
TNKPNO+CMTI10                        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      63  0
EUBKWD+CMMI6                         Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes     50  0
Times-Roman                          Type 1            Standard         no  no  no      27  0
WUHOVD+MSBM10                        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes     46  0
TXXCOH+CMMI8                         Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes     44  0
WENRPZ+CMSY10                        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes     42  0
UKDDMC+CMR8                          Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      40  0
DZKPHZ+CMMI12                        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes     38  0
QGXROH+CMR12                         Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      36  0
WFOOEY+CMMI10                        Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no      34  0
JFGGLS+CMCSC10                       Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no      32  0
JNCOFM+CMR10                         Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      30  0
BNDGFL+CMBX12                        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      28  0
THENUM+CMSS12                        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      84  0
BQAVRP+CMEX10                        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      98  0
DCOWCX+CMTI12                        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no     110  0
SFKKYE+CMSY8                         Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    107  0
SDEAPX+rsfs10                        Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     100  0
AGBIOF+CMSY6                         Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    125  0
ONCRWT+MSAM10                        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    117  0
GFZVVH+CMR6                          Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     257  0
CZBFJH+CMR7                          Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     322  0
BBIJMN+CMTT10                        Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     317  0
ZVTVKO+CMBX10                        Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     313  0
```

As you can see "Times-Roman" isn't in the PDF and probably substituted with a wrong font.

**Things to try:**

- Open the terminal application and install the Windows fonts, which
  include Times New Roman:

  `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`
- Install another pdf reader, which may be substititung the font differently, e.g. muPdf

  `sudo apt-get install mupdf`

  Right click on the PDF and choose the program to open the file
- Modify the original PDF:
  See [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277418/the-pdf-viewer-evince-on-linux-can-not-display-some-math-symbols-correctly)

Comment: Okay. Installing `mscorefonts` won't solve the problem. `Mupdf` shows the document correctly. I also tried to modify the pdf but had a problem: `/usr/bin/gs -o gs-repaired--- ../../Downloads/1210.3720.pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sDEVICE=pdfwrite 1210.3720.pdf Error: /undefinedfilename in (1210.3720.pdf) ... Last OS error: No such file or directory GPL Ghostscript 9.06: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1.` But thanks for showing `mupdf` as this is new software for me!